# Finding all instances of a word in a string with SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to search a column for all instances of a string

For example, if I have this a column with the value `all good all bad all better` I want to find the number of instances of `all`.

I tried

```
select instr(column, 'all') from test_table;
```

but that only returns the position of the first occurrence of `all`. I'm using Oracle 11g database.

Is there a way I can find all instances of a specific string in Oracle db?

Comment: first thing i thought of was the CHARINDEX function, but then I saw Oracle. I have only been working in Oracle for about a month now, but this might help you. http://nishantrana.wordpress.com/2007/10/03/using-left-and-charindex-in-oracle/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're on 11g, you can use the [`regexp_count` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions135.htm#SQLRF20014).  If you want to do a case-sensitive count

```
SELECT regexp_count( column, 'all' )
  FROM table_name
```

If you want a case-insensitive count

```
SELECT regexp_count( column, 'all', 1, 'i' )
  FROM table_name
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT REGEXP_COUNT(column, 'all') AS Cnt
FROM test_table;
```

Comment: Oracle has a regexp_count function (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions135.htm#SQLRF20014).  If you're going to use a regular expression, you should be using that.

Answer (score 0):

This works with MySQL - have not tested with Oracle but I see no reason why it wouldn't work:

```
SELECT (LENGTH(column) - LENGTH(REPLACE(column, 'all', '')))/LENGTH('all') FROM table
```